# Changing Image.Grab.grab(value) without retyping

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

A list helped me make a loop which grabs a part of the screen and compare it to a existing RGB value. Final code is in final edit. Full learnprocess is shown below.

I'm new to coding in general. I am using pixels do verify RGB value of a pixel which declares position of player. But in stead of re-typing location = ImageGrab.grab(position) can I change the position?

```
seat0 = (658,848,660,850) #btn
seat1 = (428,816,429,817) #co
seat2 = (406,700,407,701) #hj
seat3 = (546,653,547,654) #lj
seat4 = (798,705,799,706) #bb
seat5 = (769,816,770,817) #sb
btnpos = ImageGrab.grab(seat0)
position = btnpos.load()
btn = (251,0,8)
if position[0,0] == btn:
    print('Button')
elif ????
```

So I want to change seat0 (in imagegrab) to seat1 without re-typing the code. Thanks for the help

EDIT1: So I tried Marks suggestion, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
positie = ["(658,848,660,850)","(428,816,430,818)","(406,700,408,702)","(546,653,548,655)","(798,705,799,706)","(769,816,770,817)"]
btn = (251,0,8)
btnpos = ImageGrab.grab(positie[0])
btncheck = btnpos.load()
btn [0,0] not in positie[0]
```

I get "ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)"

I am trying to RGB value of positie[0] and it has to match btn. if it doesn't match to btn then it has to check positie[1], until it returns true.

Edit2:

Thanks so far Mark. I am so bad at loops.

```
positie = [(658,848,660,850),(428,816,430,818),(406,700,408,702),(546,653,548,655),(798,705,799,706),(769,816,770,817)]
btn = (251,0,8)
btnpos = ImageGrab.grab(positie[0])
btncheck = btnpos.load()
for x in positie:
    #btncheck = btnpos.load()
    if btncheck[0,0] ==btn:
        print("positie is BTN")
    else:
        btnpos = (positie[++1])
        print(btnpos)
```

how do I change btnpos with adding up instead of re-typing everything?
So it's supposed to grab first item in list and compare it to btn. If it's correct it can break, if it's wrong it has to compare btn with second item in list.
If true it gives me the position. If false:
Now it prints list[1] six times.
Thank you for your patience

FINAL EDIT: Thank you Mark.

```
positie = [(658,848,660,850),(428,816,430,818),(406,700,408,702),(546,653,548,655),(798,705,799,706),(769,816,770,817)]
btn = (251,0,8)
counter = 0
max_index = len(positie) - 1

while counter <= max_index:

    btnpos = ImageGrab.grab(positie[counter])
    btncheck = btnpos.load()
    if btncheck[0,0] == btn:
        print("Positie")
        break
    else:
        print("controleert de volgende")
        counter = counter + 1
```

Comment: Can not understand what you want to do.Is there any errors in your code?

Comment: You need to make a `list` of the seat positions and then iterate through the list - see *"Loop Through a List"* here... https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

Comment: Thank you Mark, edited my post. Can you check what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Get rid of the double quotes as they are not strings of text.

Comment: Comment out the 5 lines of your `if/else` statement and, in their place, put `print(x)` so you see how it works.

Comment: Thank you Mark. I made it work and now understand it thanks to sololearn tutorial. Final code in Edit. Thanks again.

Comment: Cool - good luck with your project.